How to calculate Running balance in RDLC reports?
I have an application that uses C#, Entity framework core & MySql database for tracking income & expense and i'm using RDLC for reporting.
I have a transactions table for tracking income and expense like
+----------------+------------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| transaction_id | transaction_date | amount   | direction |     Description |
+----------------+------------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
|              1 | 2024-07-23       |  6500.00 | Dr        |   Sale          |
|              2 | 2024-07-23       |  7100.00 | Dr        |   Sale          |
|              3 | 2024-07-23       |  7100.00 | Cr        |   Purchase      |
|              4 | 2024-07-23       |  3000.00 | Dr        |   Sale          |
|              5 | 2024-07-23       |  3000.00 | Cr        |   Purchase      |
+----------------+------------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+

I use 2 tables in the report design filtered by direction of the transaction and I'm able to display them side by side like this.
The code I use for setting the datasource for the report
var transactions = context.Transactions.ToList();
var income = from inc in transactions.Where(x=>x.Direction == "Dr") select new {inc.TransactionId, inc.TransactionDate, inc.Amount, inc.Direction, inc.Description};
var expense = from exp in transactions.Where(x=>x.Direction == "Cr") select new {exp.TransactionId, exp.TransactionDate, exp.Amount, exp.Direction, exp.Description};

ReportDataSource incomeDS = new ReportDataSource("In", income);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(incomeDS);

ReportDataSource expenseDS = new ReportDataSource("Ex", expense);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(expenseDS);


Using these 2 datasets I get the data splitted to have 2 tables in the report and be able to populate the report.
+----------------+------------------+-----------------+----------+       +----------------+------------------+-----------------+----------+ 
| transaction_id | transaction_date |     Description | amount   |   | transaction_id | transaction_date |     Description | amount   | 
+----------------+------------------+-----------------+----------+   +----------------+------------------+-----------------+----------+ 
|              1 | 2024-07-23       |   Sale          |  6500.00 |   |              3 | 2024-07-23       |   Purchase      |  7100.00 | 
|              2 | 2024-07-23       |   Sale          |  7100.00 |   |              5 | 2024-07-23       |   Purchase      | 30000.00 | 
|              4 | 2024-07-23       |   Sale          |  3000.00 |   +----------------+------------------+-----------------+----------+ 
+----------------+------------------+-----------------+----------+


But Now, I want the RDLC report to have a running balance column/ like below. I'm not sure if this can be achieved by adding new column or it needs new table with only balance column. In either case I don't know the which RDLC functions to use to implement this.

OPENING BALANCE: 10000
+------------------+-----------------+----------+  +------------------+-----------------+----------+  +------------+
| transaction_date |     Description | amount   |  | transaction_date |     Description | amount   |  | Balance    |  opening balance + income - expense
+------------------+-----------------+----------+  +------------------+-----------------+----------+  +----------- +
| 2024-07-23       |   Sale          |  6500.00 |  | 2024-07-23       |   Purchase      |  7100.00 |  |   9400.00  |   10000 + 6500 -  9400
| 2024-07-23       |   Sale          |  7100.00 |  | 2024-07-23       |   Purchase      | 30000.00 |  | -13500.00  |    9400 + 7100 - 30000
| 2024-07-23       |   Sale          |  3000.00 |  +------------------+-----------------+----------+  |  10500.00  |  -13500 + 3000  
+------------------+-----------------+----------+                                                     +------------+



I don't understand why you would want a report like that.  That's not a standard accounting report.  I can see splitting debits and credits and doing a separate summary line for each side, like a profit/loss report.  Or, I can see having everything all in one list with a running total, like a ledger report.  But what you've described seems pointless.

I understand it's not the standard and it's not exactly in a double entry system. I'm able to calculate running balance for each transaction like the usual, but the requirement is to replicate a template in excel. I thought it would be easier in the RDLC too, but I don't have much knowledge about the functions in there. Here you can see how it's done in excel https://imgur.com/a/w8vkgeU

You need to create a macro in mysql.  First create a temporary table (view) in the database : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html.  The view can be a copy of an existing table.  Then create a macro that adds running total column : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/component__implementation_8h.htmlml.  Then you can query the temporary table.

Sometimes, it's easier to pre-calculate sub-totals, and merge those "records" in with the detail; with the appropriate "breaks" and descriptions. That's where "multi-pass" comes from. Or add a (new) "tramp" colum to the detail with any "running" totals (that you pre-calculated).
